# Tutorial for setting up PhpStorm to work with Joomla

Tags: cms, development, extensions

Is there a good resource or tutorial which explains how to setup [PhpStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) so one can develop and debug Joomla extensions (and core) with it?

I am looking for something similar to the [Configuring Eclipse for Joomla! development](http://docs.joomla.org/Configuring_Eclipse_for_joomla_development) tutorial.

A lot of people seem to be happy with it, but I struggled to get it to work and gave up.

Comment: I am using Eclipse with PDT and it's worth having comparing with paid PhpStorm.

Comment: Just for reference, I use PhpEd from Nusphere.  It now recognizes and works with the Joomla Framework...pretty nice.  http://www.sitepoint.com/4-features-make-choose-nusphere-phped/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I must admit that switching from Eclipse to PhpStorm is not the easiest (as the whole IDE is quite different) thing but it's worth the effort.

You cannot have multiple projects opened in the same IDE window, and also the Git client is not as good as the one in Eclipse (actually I find it so poor, that I am using git only from the console now). But apart from that it should be very easy to run the debugger or  unit tests.

There are some **video tutorials** which may get you started.

[PhpStorm Documentation - Video Tutorials](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/documentation/phpstorm-video-tutorials.jsp)

Apart from that, the good ol' **documentation** may answer your questions.

[PhpStorm Web Help](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/phpstorm.html)

Comment: I was now able to set up and use PHPStorm and the Video Tutorials were indeed very helpful to get how it's supposed to work. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 9):

So I just spent the day setting up PHPStorm for the purpose of component development. Although it was a bit of work, now that I've finished the setup my life is going to be SOOOO much easier. I don't have a tutorial to point you to, but here is the step-by-step for setting up PHPStorm with Git, VirtualBox, Vagrant, and Joomlatools/box

1. Install PHPStorm
2. Install git
3. Install VirtualBox
4. Install Vagrant
5. Add `git` to your environmental variables. (If you're on windows 7 [this should help](http://blog.countableset.ch/2012/06/07/adding-git-to-windows-7-path/))
6. Open PHPStorm and create a new project
7. Open the terminal and type the following:

> vagrant box add joomlatools/box

8.Wait for the download to complete.Then type:

> vagrant init joomlatools/box
>
> vagrant up

Now you have a full fledged Joomla development environment with a `joomla` command tool for installing test sites on the fly. You can find the information about using the command tool [here](https://github.com/joomlatools/joomla-console)

I hope this helps! Happy Joomla!ng

I forgot to mention that if you run into a problem with getting the Virtual box to start up via the `vagrant up` command, you should set PHPStorm to run as administrator.

Comment: This is golden.

Comment: @Xerosigma I'm glad you found it useful! =^D This set up has definitely made my life easier.